# why I can not see google adwords api request times in my develop console?

Tags: google-ads-api

I have enable Google ads api ，and I request for many times last month by google adwords api. Why it doesn't show in the develop console? i just can see several times request for youtube api. Is it because I use Google adwrods api? my project  is developed by google adwords api,not google ads api..

[develop console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qR3bT.png)

Answer (score 0):

[Google Adwords API](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/start) is not part of the Cloud Developer console. You can't configure it there (apart from setting up an OAuth2 client), and any requests to it won't be visible within the console.

The [Google Ads API](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/start) on the other hand is supported.